# Compare SELECT AS to value

Tags: mysql, sql

With this query

```
SELECT least(col1, col2, col3) AS fancyTitle
FROM table
ORDER BY fancyTitle
```

how can `fancyTitle` be compared to a value so that I only output the values that are higher than 100, for example.

Comment: You can't `GROUP BY something` when `something` is an alias.

Comment: Do you want only 1 row returned, the Sum of col1 and col2 and col3, and only in the case that this sum is over 100?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I actually meant `ORDER BY`. Yes, to your question.

Comment: If there is one row only in the result, no need to `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Why didn't you just put `least` in the original question? Okay, so *now*, you want the records where the minimum across all 3 columns is greater than 100? Also, what is the primary key column(s) in this table?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I had the question of sorting `AS` values and didn't pay much attention to the rest. I was looking for the `having` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `+` operators between the columns you want to `SUM()`. You can't pass in a comma-separated list to `SUM()`

You can do:

```
SELECT id, SUM(col1 + col2+ col3) AS fancyTitle
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) > 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) AS fancyTitle
FROM table
HAVING SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) > 100 ;
```

---

MySQL allows this, too (not recommended but it will do the same):

```
SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) AS fancyTitle
FROM table
HAVING fancyTitle > 100 ;
```

---

Or perhaps you want just this:

```
SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 AS fancyTitle
FROM table
WHERE col1 + col2 + col3 > 100 
ORDER BY fancyTitle ;
```

Comment: @Random, there is no need for a `GROUP BY` since it is implicit that the grouping happens across all rows. Only one row is returned as the `SUM()`, and the `HAVING` just excludes the row if the sum is <= 100

Comment: @Random, actually, good catch. I think we need more information from the OP.

Comment: @ZaneBien Ok, I just made the query up, which probably wasn't a smart idea. But now I get how it works though. I should replace the query with a working one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT sum(col1, col2, col3) AS fancyTitle
FROM table where sum(col1, col2, col3) > 100
GROUP BY fancyTitle;
```